# display UIView with UIActivityIndicatorView when it takes a long time to do something

Tags: iphone, ios

I have some codes to process a large size file, it will take a long time.
I hope to display a view with UIActivityIndicatorView when the progress starts and hide the view when it completed

The code as below

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DisplayProcessing" object:nil];

[self dosomething];//take a long time                   

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HideProcessing" object:nil];
```

but its excution order is:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DisplayProcessing" object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HideProcessing" object:nil];

[self dosomething];//take a long time
```

so there is nothing display

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you use thread? start your indicator in method dosomething and then stop that indicator

start indicator in main method and replace

`[self dosomething];`

with

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dosomething:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

and stop your activity here